# error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying displaying widget 'widg' in layer on MainWindow after pushing 'pushButton_2' but I'm receive this error: "expected primary-expression before ')' token"

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "widg.h"
#include "ui_widg.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton_2, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(slotPush2()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::slotPush2()
{
    ui->verticalLayout_3->addWidget(widg);
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void slotPush2();
};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

widg.h

```
#ifndef WIDG_H
#define WIDG_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class widg;
}

class widg : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit widg(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~widg();

private:
    Ui::widg *ui;
};

#endif // WIDG_H
```

widg.cpp

```
#include "widg.h"
#include "ui_widg.h"

widg::widg(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::widg)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

widg::~widg()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Please, help me, what is my mistake?

Comment: Line 22, "ui->verticalLayout_3->addWidget(widg);"

Comment: How are `ui` and `widg` defined? And does `ui` have a member called `verticalLayout_3`?

Comment: I created their in designer Qt. I'm a beginner in qt. widg added as follows: "Add new (right click on project) -> Qt Designer Form Class -> Widget"

Comment: Seems to be that ui is only defined  in MainWindow's constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand precisely what your intentions are, but perhaps you meant this:

```
void MainWindow::slotPush2()
{
    ui->verticalLayout_3->addWidget(new widg(this));
}
```